# SQL Pattern name of using multiple tables and referencing with ID

Tags: sql, design-patterns

I'm looking for a name of the following pattern:

Let's say, you have a database table with a price and the amount of purchased goods. You want to calculate and save the overall price. You could save the price directly in the original table. But I I learned it is good practise to create a different table and reference the price table by ID.

For my thesis I need to cite and explain this pattern. However, I don't know which name to look for. Can you give me a hint?

[image]

Comment: I doubt this really has a name because I have no idea why anyone would consider it good practice to store data redundantly (a well-known *anti* pattern in databases) and when they do, to store it in a separate table when there's a 1-1 relationship. Ask whoever taught you this what they call it, I'd say.